# Iterate through singly-linked list in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, linked-list

I have a table with a primary (unique) key `id` and a foreign key `next_id` which points to another (next) entry in this same table (or to none if it's the last entry).

So the example data may look like this:

```
| id        |    next_id |
| --------  | ---------- |
| 1         | 3          |
| 2         | null       |
| 3         | 2          |
```

What's the most effective SQL-query to iterate through such linked list in Posgres and return list of linked id's (would be `[1, 3, 2]` for the provided example table)?

Comment: A [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out using the recursive query as suggested in comments by @Laurenz Albe

```
WITH recursive tmp_table as (
        SELECT id
        FROM main_table
        WHERE id = 1
    UNION
        SELECT m.id
        FROM main_table m
        INNER JOIN tmp_table t ON t.next_id = m.id
)

SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
```